# Typescript: Using the type of a static inner class

Tags: typescript, inner-classes

I'm trying to write a class that exposes an inner data structure to its consumers, a data structure that the class itself will be using.

Example:

```
class Outer {
    static Inner = class {
        inInner: number
    };

    constructor(public inner: Outer.Inner) { }
}
```

The problem here is that `Outer.Inner` is not recognized as a type.

The only answers that I've found are [workarounds (in Typescript playground)](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=module%20Workaround1%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20class%20Outer%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20static%20Inner%20%3D%20class%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20inInner%3A%20number%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20inner%3A%20OuterInner)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20REMOVE%3A%20Outer.Inner%20is%20not%20recognized%20as%20a%20type%2C%20so%20this%20workaround%20is%20needed%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20innerInstance%20%3D%20new%20Outer.Inner()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%20OuterInner%20%3D%20typeof%20innerInstance%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Spec%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20outer1%20%3D%20new%20Outer(%7B%20inInner%3A%203%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20outerInner%20%3D%20new%20Outer.Inner()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20outer2%20%3D%20new%20Outer(outerInner)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Amodule%20Workaround2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20class%20Outer%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20inner%3A%20Outer.Inner)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Reduced%20code%20readability%2C%20not%20clear%20why%20a%20namespace%20is%20necessary%20or%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20that%20it%27s%20simulating%20an%20inner%20class%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20namespace%20Outer%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20export%20class%20Inner%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20inInner%3A%20number%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Spec%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20outer1%20%3D%20new%20Outer(%7B%20inInner%3A%203%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20outerInner%20%3D%20new%20Outer.Inner()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20outer2%20%3D%20new%20Outer(outerInner)%3B%0D%0A%7D). I'm wondering if there are any elegant ways of doing this.

---

### Usecase:

I have a bunch of Actions that are sent over WebSockets between client and server. Each `Action` has its own `Data` inner class. The `Data` class itself is used elsewhere on the server. I could separate this into two classes (or an interface), like `Action1`, `Action1Data`, but I think that `Action1.Data` is a more readable design.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your second "workaround" is the prefer way to go:

```
class Outer {
    constructor(public inner: Outer.Inner) { }
}

namespace Outer {
    export class Inner {
        inInner: number
    };
}

// Spec
let outer1 = new Outer({ inInner: 3 });

let outerInner = new Outer.Inner();
let outer2 = new Outer(outerInner);
```

There are three types of declarations in TypeScript: namespace, type, and value.
You could use `namespace` to organize types and value.

http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html

It does not reduce readability because there is no concept of an "Inner Class" in TypeScript.

Remember that the `class` syntax is just sugar of es5 prototypal inheritance.
How would you represent an inner class in prototypal inheritance? Do you put is as an instance variable? or under `Outer.prototype.???`

what it ends up in es5 is something like this:

```
var Outer = function Outer(...) { ... }
Outer.Inner = function Inner() { ... }
```

If you look at it, the `Outer` in `Outer.Inner` is only served as a "namespace" to hold the `Inner` class.

Comment: Thanks for the Typescript handbook reference! I hadn't realized that namespaces can be officially used for declaration merging.

Comment: I use the solution you provided. However, there is one problem. Suppose, that Outer class is in ES6 module and  is exported. But we don't want to export Outer.Inner. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Since `Inner` is used in the public property of `Outer`, you need to expose it. This namespace trick helps minimize the top level types by tuck it under `Outer`.

If you really don't want to expose it, you can consider inline your type directly. But there are limitations.

Comment: This does not satisfy the case when the inner class is private.

Comment: @TomaszGawel yes, but then if the class is really private, you don't need to expose it.

Doing `Outer.Inner = ` is exposing it.

Comment: @unional you want syntax highlighting in internal usage too.

Comment: @TomaszGawel that is fine. And it depends on what do you mean by private.
Private to the file or private to the module. Private to the file you don't need export.
Private to the module you don't need to tug under the Outer class. Just don't export it at module level.

Comment: There is no need of such concept in JavaScript. Local class inside a file is private.

Answer (score 9):

I found a better workaround for this, that even allows the inner class to access the private members of the outer class, like you would expect in a C#-like language. You can actually easily get the type of the static property with the `typeof` operator. This small modification to your example works:

```
class Outer
{
    static Inner = class
    {
        inInner: number = 0;
    };

    constructor(public inner: typeof Outer.Inner.prototype) { }
}
```

But referring to the type as `typeof Outer.Inner.prototype` gets cumbersome really quickly, so add in this underneath and you can simply refer to it as `Outer.Inner` as you'd like:

```
namespace Outer
{
    export type Inner = typeof Outer.Inner.prototype;
}
```

Combine this with another workaround to allow us to put decorators on the class by making it not an anonymous class and we end up with a fully functional true inner class:

```
class Outer
{
    static Inner = (() =>
    {
        @decoratable()
        class OuterInner
        {
            inInner: number = 0;
        }
        return OuterInner;
    })();

    constructor(public inner: Outer.Inner) { }
}

namespace Outer
{
    export type Inner = typeof Outer.Inner.prototype;
}
```

Comment: You can also use `export type Inner = InstanceType<typeof Outer.Inner>;`