# Re-factor TypeScript code with declaration merging to ES2015 module syntax

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, typescript-eslint

I have a class and a namespace with declaration merging defined as follows:

```
// product.ts

export class Product {
  constructor(public name: string, public seller: Product.Seller, public price: Product.Price) {}
}

export namespace Product {
  export class Seller {
    constructor(public name: string, public country: string) {}
  }

  export class Price {
    constructor(public currency: string, public value: number) {}
  }
}

export default Product
```

I can import it in another file and use Product, Product.Seller and Product.Price to create new object as well as for type checking:

```
// index.js

import Product from './product'
    
function discountPrice(price: Product.Price, discount: number): Product.Price {
  return new Product.Price(price.currency, price.value * discount)
}

const seller = new Product.Seller('John', 'US')
const price = new Product.Price('USD', 749.9)
const priceWithDiscount = discountPrice(price, 0.7)
const product = new Product('Dell Laptop', seller, priceWithDiscount)
```

Everything is working well until I lint the file. I got the error "ES2015 module syntax is preferred over custom TypeScript modules and namespaces."

The error is kind of intuitive and I can easily get rid of it by removing the namespace and import product.ts as a named module:

```
// product.ts

export class Product {
  constructor(public name: string, public seller: Seller, public price: Price) {}
}

export class Seller {
  constructor(public name: string, public country: string) {}
}

export class Price {
  constructor(public currency: string, public value: number) {}
}

// index.js

import * as Product from './product'
```

The problem is, now the Product class itself is inside the Product module and I have to refer to it as Product.Product:

```
const product = new Product.Product('Laptop', seller, priceWithDiscount)
```

I made another attempt to export default the Product class anonymously, but I still get an error and ended up I have to refer to it as Product.default:

```
// product.ts

export default class {
  constructor(public name: string, public seller: Seller, public price: Price) {}
}

...

// index.ts

const product = new Product.default('Laptop', seller, priceWithDiscount)
```

Is it possible to retain the outcome of the original design while adhering to the no-namespace rule? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

With the namespace, the two inner classes essentially became properties of the `Product` constructor. You can still achieve that with static members:

```
export class Seller {
  constructor(public name: string, public country: string) { }
}
export class Price {
  constructor(public currency: string, public value: number) { }
}

export class Product {
  constructor(public name: string, public seller: Seller, public price: Price) { }
  static Seller = Seller
  static Price = Price
}

export default Product;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Bergi. Your solution works well in terms of object creation, however I then got an error from the discountPrice function which uses Product.Price as the param type and return type. The error says, "'Product' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here.ts(2702)". Any further suggestions on how to tackle this?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to refer to the type as just `Price`, not `Product.Price`. If you really want to have `Product` be both a class and a namespace for types, I don't think there's a way around using `namespace` syntax.

Comment: Alternatively, [an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42864291/1048572) suggests `typeof Product.Price.prototype` as a workaround, but I think that's really ugly.

Comment: By looking at the link you shared, the accepted answer does exactly what I did initially. The second answer is kind of an alternative to that and it still wraps `typeof Product.Price.prototype` into a namespace. (I get that I can directly use that for type checking, but as you pointed out it is really ugly.) Perhaps I should take a step back to understand the rationale behind the no-namepace rule, and see whether it brings enough benefit to outweigh the pain. Thanks again for your help and I'll revert back once I think through it.

Comment: Just do away with the default export altogether, and consume everything via named imports: `import { Product } from './product';`.. If you still want to do a grouped namespace import of things, you can do that with `import * as Product from './product';`